# I'm having trouble implementing the Atmega328 timer into my arduino networking

Tags: networking, arduino

I am trying to implement error correction over an r/f communication between two arduinos. I tried adding a timer to it, in order to create a packet resend, but whenever it gets past the first send, it starts printing garbage ad infinity instead of doing the timer interrupt.

I tried messing around with the inside loop conditions some as well as trying to figure out what was wrong with the timer, but I couldn't figure it out. The problem seems to happen right around the first serial print, which is strange, because that part of the code is mostly unchanged.
(packets is a structure of two ints)

```
#include <ELECHOUSE_CC1101.h>
#include "packets.h"

// These examples are from the Electronics Cookbook by Simon Monk
// Connections (for an Arduino Uno)
// Arduino          CC1101
// GND              GND
// 3.3V             VCC
// 10               CSN/SS   **** Must be level shifted to 3.3V
// 11               SI/MOSI  **** Must be level shifted to 3.3V
// 12               SO/MISO
// 13               SCK      **** Must be level shifted to 3.3V
// 2                GD0

const int n = 61;
unsigned short int sequence = 0;
byte buffer[n] = "";


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Set line ending to New Line in Serial Monitor.");
  Serial.println("Enter Message");
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.Init(F_433); // set frequency - F_433, F_868, F_965 MHz
  // initialize timer1 

  noInterrupts();           // disable all interrupts

  TCCR1A = 0;

  TCCR1B = 0;

  TCNT1 = 0;


  OCR1A = 0xFFFF; // Max value for overflow for now

  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);    // 256 prescaler 



  interrupts();             // enable all interrupts

}
Packet pckt, recieve;

ISR(TIMER1_OVR_vect){          // timer compare interrupt service routine
    //Resend packet
    ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SendData(buffer, pckt.data + pckt.seqNum);
    int len = ELECHOUSE_cc1101.ReceiveData(buffer);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    recieve.seqNum = buffer[n];
    Serial.println("Interrupt");


}


void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    pckt.data = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, n);
    pckt.seqNum = sequence;
    buffer[pckt.data] = '\0';
    buffer[n-1] = pckt.seqNum;
    Serial.println((char *)buffer);

    ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SendData(buffer, pckt.data + pckt.seqNum);
    TCNT1 = 0; // clear timer
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE0);  // enable timer compare interrupt
    int len = ELECHOUSE_cc1101.ReceiveData(buffer);
    while (recieve.seqNum <= sequence) {

    }
    TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << TOIE0); // turn off the timer interrupt

  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably with your handling of `buffer`..  But sending and receiving data from the timer ISR is _not_ a good idea, and your issue could also come from there...

Comment: How would I get around those problems? And why is sending data not a good idea via the interrupt? Does it take too long?

Comment: Yes, return from a sending of a bufferload of data can take ages, sometimes several milliseconds.  The length of data you send to rthe controller is not right.  `pckt.data` already contains the length you need for Serial.write() and cc1101.SendData().  The length is wrong in your code, there are only `pckt.data` contiguous bytes of data in the buffer.  What's with `pckt.seqNum` being exiled at the end of the buffer?  If you want to prepend a sequence number, you can try this start receiving from serial port at `buffer + 1` with length of  `sizeof(buffer) -1` and place the number at `buffer[0]`

Comment: If you want to implement timeouts from loop() {}, you'll have to implement a small state machine, with 2 states:  `waitingForSerial, waitingForResponse`  You send to the CC1101 in waitingForSerial state, and handle CC1101 response and any timeouts in `waitingForResponse`state.  Use `millis()` for timing, it's simple and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Sending data takes too long for interrupts.  You should keep calls to send and receive buffers of data within the `loop()` function call tree.  For example, sending a 12 bytes message via UART at 9600 bauds can take up to about 12ms.

You can use the timer interrupt to decrement a timeout counter, as is usually done on micro controllers, or use the millis() function to handle timings, as is easily done on Arduino.

I suggest you use the millis() function to compute timeouts.

example:

```
/* ...  */

// I could not figure out what you were trying to do with 
// pckt.seqNum....  Putting it at the end of the buffer 
// makes no sense, so I've left it out.
// Moreover, its size is 2, so placing it at buffer[n-1] overflows the buffer...

enum machineState {
    waitingForSerial, 
    waitingForResponse,
};

unsigned int time_sent;  // Always use unsigned for variables holding millis()
                         // can use unsigned char for timeouts of 255  
                         // milliseconds or less. unsigned int is good for about 
                         // 65.535 seconds or less.

machineState state = waitingForSerial;

void loop()
{
    switch(state)
    {
    case waitingForSerial:
        pckt.data = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (pckt.data > 0)
        {
            ++pckt.seqNum;
            Serial.write(buffer, pckt.data);
            ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SetReceive();
            ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SendData(buffer, pckt.data);
            time_sent = millis();
            state = waitingForResponse;
       }
       break;

    case waitingForResponse:
        if (ELECHOUSE_cc1101.CheckReceiveFlag())
        {
            auto len = ELECHOUSE_cc1101.ReceiveData(buffer))  // can use C++17 with duinos!!!

            Serial.print("cc1101: ");
            Serial.write(buffer, len);
            state = waitingForSerial;  // wait for another command from PC
        }
        //  1 second timeout, note the cast and subtraction, this is to avoid any 
        //  issues with rollover of the millis() timestamp.
        else if ((unsigned int)millis() - time_sent > 1000)
        {
            // resend ...  stays stuck this way.
            Serial.println("Retrying :(");
            ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SendData(buffer, pckt.data);
            time_sent = millis();
        }
        break;

    default:
        state = waitingForSerial;
        Serial.println("unhandled state");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get some two-way messages working with your code.

Comment: I've added a necessary cast.  Sorry, but I didn't try to compile this.